# Pass data to a child components in RDK LightningJS

Tags: javascript, smart-tv

I am trying to build a page with multiple row of tiles using [LightningJS](https://rdkcentral.github.io/Lightning/). I have looked at the examples in https://github.com/rdkcentral/Lightning-UI-Components/blob/master/components/FocusManager/FocusManager.stories.js and have used ColumnWithRowsExample as my starting point. All the examples rely on data being available at the point of initializing a component.
I need to pass data down to child components dynamically, and be able to refresh them. I am unable to find how to get this info in their [samples](https://rdkcentral.github.io/Lightning-UI-Components/?path=/docs/focusmanager--column-with-rows) or [docs](https://rdkcentral.github.io/Lightning/docs/introduction/introduction#innovative-development-paradigms).
I have done trial and error for a week and have not progressed. Any snippets/samples or docs with this info would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.application.emit("func name", {data})`
and access anywhere, using `this.application.on("func name", (data)=>{ logic })`